# nginx or apache add port if in url no slash

Tags: php, apache, web, nginx

I have nginx+apache+php configuration.
If in my browser i write "http://example.com" server redirect me to "http//example.com:8080" (8080 is my Apache port), but if I add slash (like example.com/) works fine.
nginx config:

```
server {
    location / {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add in nginx configuraion line:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```